# Get data from simpe mongodb collection using orion context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

For example , I have a collection "superUser" containing this document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab1552823102117ecf77947"),
    "email" : "mail@hotmail.com",
    "username" : "abcd",
    "password" : "12345",
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe"
}
```

Can I somehow retrieve this document with fiware-orion using the GET method, or it has to be created from the begining using orion (NGSI10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion doesn't work the way you suggest. It is not a general REST wrapper for MongoDB collections (I haven't searched specifically about it but there should be a *lot* of software projects covering that use case :)

Orion works based on an entity-attribute context model. Thus, all the operations in the API (i.e. create entities, update attributes, retrieve entities, etc.) are based in such concept. All these operations are detailed in the [NGSIv2 API reference](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/).

In your case, a posible context model would be to have an `User` entity type, using the entity id to identify particular users (e.g. entity id `abcd`). The attributes of the User entities would be firstName, lastName, email and password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!